# Regex to get string inside parentheses in Java? (including another parentheses inside parentheses)

Tags: java, regex

I want to get all string inside the very first parentheses

For example, if the input :

> "1 + 2 + ( 1 + 2 + (1 + 2) ) "

It will return

> [( 1 + 2 + (1 + 2) )]

If the input :

> "1 + (1 + 2 + (1 + 2 + (1 + 2) ) )"

It will return

> ["(1 + 2 + (1 + 2 + (1 + 2) ) )"]

Comment: No you can't, regexes are the wrong tool for that. You can write a very simple function that loops over the string while keeping track of the parenthesis nesting level. While looping, only copy characters to the output string if the nesting level is 1 or greater.

Comment: You need a *parser* here. One of the restrictions of regular expressions is that they can't do the sort of counting that you need to match an arbitrary number of opening and closing braces.

Comment: For what you simply need to do, why use RegEx? Just use: `String strg = equationString.substring(equationString.indexOf("("), (equationString.lastIndexOf(")") + 1));`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pattern & Matcher classes to extract what you want as follows

```
   String input = "1 + (1 + 2 + (1 + 2 + (1 + 2) ) )";
   String regexp =  "(\\()(.*)(\\))";

   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);


   while(matcher.find()) {

       System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
   }
```

Output

> 1 + 2 + (1 + 2 + (1 + 2) )